# What approach/method to use instead of multiple if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, hashmap, logic

I have a java web app that asks the user to select between 4 options. They can choose 1, all, or any combination of the 5 options. Their choices are read into a Hashmap with true/false values. If the option is selected it's true, unselected is false. Depending on what the user chooses, a different file is selected from the resources folder to be processed. My problem is that the code is just a complete mess of logic and I'm sure that there's an easier way to implement it. The following is dummy code for my problem.

```
public class offerSelector {

public void selectOffer(Map params) {

/* Map params = Map<String, String> params = new HashMap <>();
   It contains values ("internet","true),("phone","true"),("tv","true"),("cell","true")
*/

boolean option_1 = params.get("internet");
boolean option_2 = params.get("phone");
boolean option_3 = params.get("tv");
boolean option_4 = params.get("cell");

File offer = null;

if (option_1 == true && option_2 == false && option_3 == false && option_4 == false) {
    offer = new File("internet_order");
}
else if(option_1 == false && option_2 == true && option_3 == false && option_4 == false) {
    offer = new File("phone_order");
}

//continues like so with all possible combinations
else if(option_1 == true && option_2 == true && option_3 == true && option_4 == true) {
    offer = new File("all_elements_order");
}

processOrder(offer);
}
}
```

Comment: First of all wrong operator. Use `==`. Even don't use it. In Java you can just say `if(option_1)` provided `option_1` is a boolean field.

Comment: Sorry that's just code I threw together. The syntax in my actual code is correct (I know because it works :) )

Comment: Then please post the right code.

Comment: Dude! Your code's messed up. option_1 = true will fail since you didn't use == and option_1 is not boolean.

Comment: Are there really different files for each combination? That seems quite odd.

Comment: Ok code is fixed and @Thomas yes there are individual files. They're all completely different based on the combination of options

Comment: They're all *completely* different?  That is very, very odd.  At the least, i'd think the phone+internet order would have a combination of the info merged from the phone order and internet order types.

Comment: you can use Switch case

Comment: what do you do when option4 and option1 are true and the others are false? ithink you have a design problem there

Comment: @cHao no the files are between 600-1000 lines of XML. There are certain parameters that are contained in there that are wildly different, depending on the options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a big fan Of pushing this parsing into a custom Object like

```
public class SomeObject
{
  public SomeObject(Values)
  {
     this.options1 = //Something
     this.options2 = //Something
     this.options3 = //Something
     this.options4 = //Something
  }

  public boolean isPhone() {return option1 && option2 && option3 && !option4;}
}
```

Then when you use the option you can do:

```
var x = new SomeObject(Values);
if (x.isPhone) {
  // DO IS PHONE Branch
}
if (x.isFax) {
  // DO IS Fax Branch
}
```

This is better because the parsing logic is excluded to a single class with a single responsibility. and then its clear in your if block what you are looking at.

The other options is to return an Enum from you SomeObject class and use a true case/switch statement.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of solutions. For example the following.

Define `interface Action`:

```
 interface Action {
     boolean apply(Map<String, String> params);
     void perform(Map<String, String> params);
 }
```

Define enum Actions:

```
 enum Actions implement Action {
      ONE {
            boolean apply(Map<String, String> params) {/*implement it*/}
            void perform(Map<String, String> params) {/*implement it*/}
      },
      TWO {
            boolean apply(Map<String, String> params) {/*implement it*/}
            void perform(Map<String, String> params) {/*implement it*/}
      },
      ;
      //etc.
 }
```

Implement your logic inside the call back methods. Obviously give the enum constants normal names.

Now your code can look like:

```
public void selectOffer(Map params) {
    for (Actions a : Actions.values()) {
        if (a.apply(params)) {
             return a.perform(params);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: This helps when logic is repeated. But actually inside of `implement it` you'll have the same if-combinations boilerplate, the questionee wanted to get rid of.

Answer (score 2):

Use a binary notation. each bit represents one option:

option4 is true, option3 is true, option2 is false and option1 is false will be 1100

1100 bin = 12 dec.

Each combination stands for a decimal number, which you can use in a `switch` statement.

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: This would be much better with enums or constants (like `public final int INTERNET = 0x01;`) representing each bit.

Comment: thats true! combining it which an enmu would make it more readable

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use a custom object, let's say `Options`:

```
//note that a lot of common stuff like constructors or modifiers are stripped for simplicity
class Options {
  boolean internet;
  boolean phone;
  ...

  public void equals( Object other) {
    return other != null && 
     other.getClass().equals( getClass()) && 
     other.internet == this.internet && 
     other.phone == this.phone &&
     ...
  }    

  public int hashCode() {
    //left for your excerise, should match equals
  }
}

Map<Options, File> files = ...; //create and fill
```

Then parse the boolean parameters and create an `Options` instance which you use to look up the file in the map, e.g.:

```
 Options paramOptions = new Options(/*booleans parsed from params*/);
 offer = files.get( paramOptions  );
```

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulate it all away. Hide the details of sifting through the permutations of options in the guts of another class. Something like this...

```
//controller code
Boolean internet= params.get("internet");
Boolean phone = params.get("phone");
Boolean tv= params.get("tv");
Boolean cell = params.get("cell");    
File offer = FileHelper(internet, phone, tv, cell);
//end controller code ...


public class FileHelper {

private final String PHONE = "phone_order";
private final String INTERNET= "internet_order";
private final String CELL= "cell_order";
private final String TV = "tv_order";
private final String ALL = "all_elements_order";

private boolean[] options;

public FileHelper(Boolean phone, Boolean internet, Boolean cell, Boolean tv) {
    options = new boolean[4];
    options[0] = phone == null ? false : phone;
    options[1] = internet == null ? false : internet ;
    options[2] = cell== null ? false : cell;
    options[3] = tv == null ? false : tv ;
}

public File getOffer() {
    File f;
    if ( includeAll()) f = new File(ALL);
    if ( phoneOffer()) f = new File(PHONE);
    if ( internetOffer()) f = new File(INTERNET);
    // .... and so on

    return f;
}

private boolean includeAll() {
    for(boolean b : options) {
        if (!b) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean internetOffer() {
    return getSingleOption() == 1;    
}

private boolean phoneOffer() {
    return getSingleOption() == 0;   
}

private int getSingleOption() {
    int i = -1;

    for(int j; j =0; j++) {
        if(options[j]) {
            if ( i >= 0) {
                return -1; //user has selected > 1 option
            } else {
               i = j;
            }
        }            
    }
    return i;
}

}
```

I'm guessing the boolean[] won't be popular, but I think having such a structure gives you an easy way to determine how many options the user has flagged as true, which from your question seems like something you'd want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry not enought reputation to comment, 
first of all you can use switches: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html, it is much easier for codes like this one, and maybe for organization you can use another function that is launched from this one (Just remember to put that strings univeral)